# Download here or there?

Tags: technical

I have the following technical instructions for our software product:

1. Go to ~/directory
2. Download **here** [link to the file]
3. Execute the following command: [command]

Should I use here or there in the 2nd step? Or maybe you can suggest another elegant and simple way to instruct our users?

Comment: Whilst I agree with the two answers already given, the instructions might not work correctly anyway.  Going to ~/directory looks like it should be executed in a linux terminal, but because the download is a link, people will normally just click the link to download.  By default this will be to ~/Downloads in linux.  Nothing wrong with it if the first step is to ~/Downloads, but something to be aware of

Comment: You should avoid using "here" for linking things. Just...always. Step two should probably read: "Download _filename.ext_ to ~/directory" (or wherever you wanted it downloaded) and link _filename.ext_ to the actual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download here expression is because of how relative/absolute pathing works in computer software, and how people usually like well defined places to think with.

It works better, because if you follow a list, and arrive to the step of "Download there", the question might be, where? However, if you followed the list, entered a place/navigated there, then read Download here, you know it should be done right where you are at. It makes more way more sense and less confusion.

Alternatively:
Download to [./directory] can work.

So yes, you should use download here in the 2nd step, as this is a list. In other context, like flowing text or long statements, it can work with there as well - it's just less common to structure your sentences that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think here works fine (certainly preferable to there).

Although if you are looking for an alternative, I would maybe suggest: Download **this** file